# How to create function with two closures as params in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures, func

I need to translate such a func from Objective-C to Swift language. But can't find an example and can't get how to send 2 closures into func in Swift.

For example, original function in Objective-C:

> ```
> - (void)getForDemoDataWithToken:(Token *)token
> onSuccess:(void(^)(NSArray *demoData))success
> onFailure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure {
> }
> ```

I know to send 1 closure as param:

> getForDemoDataWithToken(token) {(success: String) -> Void in
>
> // some code here
>
> print(success)
>
> }

But, how to send two closures?

Thank you

Comment: Check out this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about this?

### Declaration

```
func getForDemoDataWithToken(
    token: Token,
    onSuccess: (demoData:NSArray?) -> (),
    onFailure: (error:NSError?) -> ()) {

}
```

### Invocation

```
getForDemoDataWithToken(Token(),
    onSuccess: { (demoData) -> () in

    },
    onFailure: { (demoData) -> () in

    }
)
```

### A more Swifty approach

I usually see Swift code where only **one closure** is used. So instead of 2 distinct `onSuccess` and `onFailure` closures you could have just `completion`.

Next we should remember that `NSArray` is compatible with Swift but it's not the *Swiftest* way to use an array.

Let's see an example where the 2 concepts above are applied.

```
func getForDemoData(token:Token, completion:(data:[Foo]?, error:NSError?) -> ()) {

}
```

You can invoke it with the `trailing closure` syntax.

```
getForDemoData(Token()) { (data, error) -> () in
    if let data = data where error == nil {
        // success!
    } else {
        // oh no... something wrong here
    }
}
```

Comment: I just though about this. Will try. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you wanna mention the `Result<Error, Value>` type as well, would actually be more fitting for this than two optionals.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the closures as normal parameters, like this:

```
func acceptsTwoClosures(
    onSuccess onSuccess: (success: String) -> Void,
    onFailure: (failure: String) -> Void) {

        onSuccess(success: "Ook")
        onFailure(failure: "Eek")
}

acceptsTwoClosures(
    onSuccess: { print("Success: \($0)") },
    onFailure: { print("Failure: \($0)") }
)

// In the playground the above prints:
//  
// Success: Ook
// Failure: Eek
```

The way that you used in the question is called *trailing closure*, and it only works for the closures that are the **last** arguments in the function signature.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102):

> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can be useful to write it as a *trailing closure* instead. A trailing closure is a closure expression that is written outside of (and *after*) the parentheses of the function call it supports.

For example, you could also re-write my suggested snippet from above like this:

```
acceptsTwoClosures(onSuccess: { print("Success: \($0)") }) {
    print("Failure: \($0)")
}
```

.. as you can see, I can pass the second (i.e. the *last*) closure outside of `acceptsTwoClosures` call as a trailing closure, but I still have to pass the first one as a normal parameter.

Comment: I tried this approach in playground - it didn't work. Maybe it was syntax mistake.

Comment: I just re-checked, it does work on my machine.  Which version of XCode you are using?

Comment: Xcode version 7.0.1 (7A1001); OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.1 (15B42)

Comment: Strange.  Here is a working version:  http://swiftstub.com/444436078  What is the difference from your case?

Comment: Sorry, had to abandon case with two closures because of lack of time for investigation. Started using trailing closure. Thank you very much for help.